# Read heavy table deadlocks in mysql

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I'm seeing a high number of deadlocks when attempting to update a table that gets read frequently.

deadlocked_table is an InnoDB table.

I'm running MySQL 5.1

I've narrowed it down to 2 possibilities:

1. High volume of reads on `deadlocked_table` causing issues... these are non-locking selects
2. Insert into a memory table where the source data is my deadlocked table ie:

   `insert different_table select * from deadlocking_table where...`

In the 2nd circumstance `different_table` is a Memory Table.

I think my solution is going to be to change the isolation level for both circumstances to `read uncommitted`, but I'd like to know definitively if a high volume of reads or an insert into memory tables could cause my update statement to deadlock.

Comment: You can reduce the number of deadlocks you see by a great deal of amount if you write your update statements carefully.
If you want to update rows, always run a query to select the ids of the row, and them make updates using those ids. Update statements with no Primary key specified in the where clause is a bad idea for a table with high traffic. Hope this helps.